# How to add active class to a sidebar menu using page url?

Tags: jquery

This is my JQuery code so far.

```
var url = window.location;
$('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

This works for /category or any other menu. But when the url is like /category/create or /category?page=2 the code is not adding the active class to the menu. Where should I change the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var url = window.location;
 $('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
    return (url.indexOf(this.href)>-1) ? true : false;
 }).parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Nope it's not working. It is not adding any class at all.

Comment: Can you please share the values of `this.href` and `url` in order to get the `active` class added?

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand what are you asking for. Something like this?? http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/create

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Yes and what is the link of `href`?

Comment: As I am using a resource controller of Laravel the href is simply {{ url('product') }} for the sidebar menu. In the Product page the Add Product button url is {{ url('product/create') }}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to add an active class in the sidebar. Try this code.

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
            var baseurl = document.location.origin; 
            jQuery('ul.sidebar-menu li').each(function(){
                var sidebarurl = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
                  var sidebarurl1 = sidebarurl.split('?')[0];
                            var remain_sidebar_url  = sidebarurl1.replace(baseurl,'');

                            if(remain_sidebar_url == url){
                            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                            }
            });
```

Comment: The code is working same as my own code. OK for /product but does not work for product/create